# One liner to access an array element in perl?

Tags: perl

I have the following:

```
my @path = split( "/", getcwd );
my $grandParent = $path[-2];
```

I'd like to do it in one line (like in other languages) since I'm not using @path again, like so:

```
my $grandParent = split( "/", getcwd )[-2];
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

EDIT: Just to be clear - where I am running the script from I know some things are going to be invariant (the directory structure, names, etc). This being said, validation is nice, but in this scenario is more clutter than it is worth; thanks to those who submitted solutions with error checking any ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

should be:

```
use Cwd;
...

my $grandParent = ( split '/', getcwd ) [-2];
```

**Addendum:**
another way (somehow more 'perlish'):

```
...

my ($parent, $grandParent) = reverse split qr{/}, getcwd();
```

(taking into account some of [tchrist's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109271/one-liner-to-access-an-array-element-in-perl/4109566#4109566) good advice)

**Addendum 2:**
Some comment:

Sometimes, there might not be a `$grandparent` directory at all.
If used in the root dir on a Unix system '/', above will
result in:

```
 $parent = undef;
 $grandParent = undef;
```

if in a directory directly below '/', eg. '/somedir',

```
 $parent = 'somedir';
 $grandParent = ''; # empty string
```

so you may check for that condition. Furthermore, the `reverse`
reverses the order of the elements of the splitted path, so you know you
need to look at the (now) first two elements to know where you are.

Regards

rbo

Comment: Thanks, I figured there was a way but I'm really new to perl :)

Comment: The Addendum is not clear to me. I actually like @zigdon's solution best, but since your first solution is clear enough, works, and was before his you get the accept :)

Comment: @javamonkey79: zigdons response was actually the first one, he was faster by about 10 seconds if I remember correctly ...

Comment: Ah, that's right - I thought that it was ordered sequentially by time, not votes. I'll keep yours accepted since you added so much. Thanks for the info, it's appreciated and generally fits the spirit of SO :)

Answer (score 6):

Put the results of the split in a temporary list:

```
my $grandParent = (split( "/", getcwd ))[-2];
```

Answer (score 4):

Thinngs to remember:

1. You have to account for not getting enough list elements back, and also for when the applicable element ends up being the empty string.
2. `split()`’s first argument is a pattern, not a string, so you should remind people of that by writing it as a match operation.
3. `getcwd()` is a nullary function, not a bareword, so you should remind people of that by using empty parens.

   ```
   $grandparent = ( split(m{ / }x, getcwd()) )[-2] || "/";
   ```

That won’t work on non-POSIX filesystems; instead, see `File::Spec`.

Please ignore SO’s idiotic colorizificationalistics, which do more harm than good.

Comment: SO's coloring is terrible for Perl, but it's pretty good or most languages. Overall, I've learned to ignore how Perl gets colored on here.

Comment: You can use `<pre>...</pre>` to turn off highlighting.

Answer (score 2):

A portable way is to use `splitdir` method of [`File::Spec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html):

```
use Cwd;
use File::Spec;

my $grand_parent = ( File::Spec->splitdir( getcwd() ) )[-2] || File::Spec->rootdir();
```

Comment: That still has the short-path bug.

Comment: tchrist: Thanks for mentioning. Fixed it.